# RavenDB: help to architecture my project

Tags: c#, ravendb

This is a personal project to get started using RavenDB.
I have been using a mxing program for years whose track data are stored in a xml file. The structure is as follow:

```
<Song attribute="" attribute="">
  <node1 attribute="" />
  <node2 attribute="" attribute="" />
  <node3 attribute="" attribute="" attribute="" />
  <node4 attribute="" attribute="" />
  <node5 attribute="" />
</Song>
<Song attribute="" attribute="">
  <node1 attribute="" />
  <node2 attribute="" />
  <node3 attribute="" />
  <node4 attribute="" attribute="" />
</Song>
```

I'd like to manipulate the data (CRUD and other niceties). After having fun, I'd like to save everything into ravenDB and then in a new xml file. As the data are xml nodes, I think it is best to import all the nodes and its content into RavenDB.
To make the design decouple from the schema, I plan to make at least 2 POCO:

DAL : `SongRecord` POCO whose properties are those from a typical node
BL : `Song` POCO more business oriented

What should I do?
JSON.NET offers to serialize/deserialize xml to json and vice versa. Once the xml is serialized into json, I can store it into RavenDB.
My BL communicates with the DAL that queries against RavenDB.

After a while I want to persist everything into the db and then export everything into a new xml file, whose schema is the one I mentionned above.

What do you think about it? Is there something wrong? What's best instead? Remember it is a pet project to learn RavenDB.

Comment: Why convert between xml and json? Performance? I haven't used raven .. can it not store xml? If it can you could just store the xml in raven in the format you want to output .. then saving will be a breeze. Architecture looks good to me tho. Have fun :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't RavenDB handle the serialization back and forth to JSON? All you should have to handle is getting your POCOs back and forth to the XML format for the mixer program. Everywhere else, leave them as POCOs.

Comment: I don't understand. Suppose RavenDB serializes back and forth to JSON. The data are persisted into the db. Values are, say, inappropriate for querying efficiently. For ex. dates are persisted in a custom way (0230061025 equals June 30, 2002 at 10:25 am). Should I fetch data into a POCO record (SongRecord) to ease the query (against a date time object?). Thanks for your help.

Comment: RavenDB will handle all of the querying details for you, you shouldn't worry about that